# Distincting table elements one from another

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm trying get data from a certain table using Jsoup parser.

Html code of the table:

```
<table class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden">
<tr>
<th width="10%">
<div style="color:black;">Ura</div>
<div style="font-size:11px;">&nbsp;</div></th>
            <th class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-th-danes">
            <div>Ponedeljek</div>
            <div style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;color:#777;">16. 12.</div>
        </th>
                    <th >
            <div>Torek</div>
            <div style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;color:#777;">17. 12.</div>
        </th>
                    <th >
            <div>Sreda</div>
            <div style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;color:#777;">18. 12.</div>
        </th>
                    <th >
            <div>Četrtek</div>
            <div style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;color:#777;">19. 12.</div>
        </th>
                    <th >
            <div>Petek</div>
            <div style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;color:#777;">20. 12.</div>
        </th>
        </tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10%" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-ura">

        <div class="black bold text14" style="padding-bottom:0px;">1. ura</div>
        <div class="text10 gray">7:00 - 7:45</div>
    </td>
                <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-1-2013-12-16" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes">
                    </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-1-2013-12-17" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
                    </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-1-2013-12-18" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Matematika">MAT</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                M. Baloh, 108                   </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-1-2013-12-19" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Izdelava osnovnih vezij praksa">IOVP</span>                       </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                R. Fele, ED5                    </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-1-2013-12-20" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Slovenščina">SLO</span>                       </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Gutman, 107                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-ura">

        <div class="black bold text14" style="padding-bottom:0px;">2. ura</div>
        <div class="text10 gray">7:50 - 8:35</div>
    </td>
                <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-2-2013-12-16" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik  ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes" style="color:#444;">                 <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Geografija">GEO</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Bec, 109                 </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-2-2013-12-17" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Angleščina">ANG</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                I. Lesjak, 106                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-2-2013-12-18" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Slovenščina">SLO</span>                       </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Gutman, 107                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-2-2013-12-19" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Izdelava osnovnih vezij praksa">IOVP</span>                       </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-blok-2-2013-12-19').toggle();stop_propagation(event);" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-vec_ur" title="Več skupin">2</a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                R. Fele, ED5                    </div>

                                </div>
            <div id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-blok-2-2013-12-19" class="ni_prvi"><div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;border-top:1px solid #E6E6E6;">                 <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Infor.s tehniškim kom. vaje">ITKV</span>                      </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Kirn, 207                    </div>

                                </div>
            </div>          </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-2-2013-12-20" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Matematika">MAT</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                M. Baloh, 108                   </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-ura">

        <div class="black bold text14" style="padding-bottom:0px;">3. ura</div>
        <div class="text10 gray">8:40 - 9:25</div>
    </td>
                <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-3-2013-12-16" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik  ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes" style="color:#444;">                 <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Slovenščina">SLO</span>                       </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Gutman, 107                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-3-2013-12-17" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Kemija">KEM</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Kovač Hace, 204                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-3-2013-12-18" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Angleščina">ANG</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                I. Lesjak, 106                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-3-2013-12-19" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Izdelava osnovnih vezij praksa">IOVP</span>                       </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-blok-3-2013-12-19').toggle();stop_propagation(event);" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-vec_ur" title="Več skupin">2</a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                R. Fele, ED5                    </div>

                                </div>
            <div id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-blok-3-2013-12-19" class="ni_prvi"><div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;border-top:1px solid #E6E6E6;">                 <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Infor.s tehniškim kom. vaje">ITKV</span>                      </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Kirn, 207                    </div>

                                </div>
            </div>          </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-3-2013-12-20" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Izdelava osnovnih vezij">IOV</span>                       </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                J. Kalšek, 112                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-ura">

        <div class="black bold text14" style="padding-bottom:0px;">4. ura</div>
        <div class="text10 gray">9:30 - 10:40</div>
    </td>
                <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-4-2013-12-16" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik  ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes" style="color:#444;">                 <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Zgodovina">ZGO</span>                     </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                V. Kralj, 109                   </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-4-2013-12-17" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Umetnost">UME</span>                      </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Bec, 109                 </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-4-2013-12-18" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Geografija">GEO</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Bec, 109                 </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-4-2013-12-19" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Angleščina">ANG</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                I. Lesjak, 106                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-4-2013-12-20" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Informatika s tehniškim komuniciranjem">ITK</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                I. Pavlič, 207                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-ura">

        <div class="black bold text14" style="padding-bottom:0px;">5. ura</div>
        <div class="text10 gray">10:45 - 11:30</div>
    </td>
                <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-5-2013-12-16" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik  ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes" style="color:#444;">                 <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Matematika">MAT</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                M. Baloh, 108                   </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-5-2013-12-17" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Slovenščina">SLO</span>                       </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Gutman, 107                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-5-2013-12-18" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Upravljanje s programirljivimi napravami">UPN</span>                      </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                R. Fele, 216                    </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-5-2013-12-19" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Kemija">KEM</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                S. Kovač Hace, 204                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
                    <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-5-2013-12-20" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik " style="color:#444;">                   <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Informatika s tehniškim komuniciranjem">ITK</span>                        </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                I. Pavlič, 207                  </div>

                                </div>
                        </td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-ura">

        <div class="black bold text14" style="padding-bottom:0px;">6. ura</div>
        <div class="text10 gray">11:35 - 12:20</div>
    </td>
                <td width="18%" id="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-6-2013-12-16" class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes">
        <div class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-urnik  ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden-td-danes" style="color:#444;">                 <table class="w100 collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border:none;" class="text14 bold"><span title="Izdelava osnovnih vezij">IOV</span>                       </td>
                    <td style="border:none;" align="right"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text11">
                J. Kalšek, 216                  </div>
//code goes on here
```

Sorry for the messy code, you can try and view the page source yourself here: https://www.easistent.com/urniki/cc45c5d0d303f954588402a186f5cdba5edb51d6/razredi/16515

But someone has already let me know that it doesn't open the page in some countries.

So if every **td** or atleast **tr** had it's own unique ID or CLASS, this wouldn't have been a problem. But they are all the same and every **td** has another **td** within itself with a class "text 14 bold" and within that **td**, there's a **span** with a certain **title**. But that title doesn't help me since if this table will ever be updated, the code will be useless because the title will be changed as well.

Or is it maybe that I've approached this the wrong way and there's a better library out there for easier html parsing?

I'm really bad at explaining and I can't explain this to any search engine so I'll appreciate it very much if someone helps.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous. What part of the HTML do you want to parse? Is it a specific <td>-element or are you just asking generally about how to separate different elements?

Comment: I basically want to parse all the <span>-elements that are within <td>-elements. Let's say for example if I wanted to parse the second row, I would get: GEO, ANG, SLO, IOVP, IOV

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation -- you can walk through them as members of an array, note especially element siblings and children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the table of interest that holds the schedule is the following:

```
<table class="ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden">
```

Each row is represented in a `tr` element inside the table body.
A- the rows can thus be selected using the css-selector with the syntax

```
Elements e = doc.select("table.ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden tbody tr span");
```

which simply tells Jsoup to select all the `span` elements inside the `tr` elements inside a `tbody` of a table with the class `ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden`. A bit nested, but simple to follow.

The output of the `text` attribute of the selected nodes would be all the text inside the `span` elements.

To separate the `tr` elements you just use the `tr:eq(n)` syntax when you select the elements. The `tr:eq(n)` tells the selector to only select the `tr` that has an index equal to `n`. element As an example, to select the values of the second row as you suggested in your comment, the following would do the trick:

```
Elements e = doc.select("table.ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden tbody tr:eq(2) span");
for (Element element : e) {
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

which will output

```
GEO
ANG
SLO
IOVP
ITKV
MAT
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I understand this much better now. I will accept your answer as soon as I try it out :) just one more question. You said in your example if I want to select the second row, I would put eq(2), but doesn't index always start at 0, meaning that the second row has an index of 1?

Comment: It does, though, if you look at the first row which has index 0 is the row that displays what time and weekday each row/column represents. The second row does not necessarily mean the second tr element.

Comment: ohhhh, yes, I misslooked that, thanks for informing me

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much, I just have one more question and then I've got everything I need. As you can see in the table, the IOVP and ITKV are in the same td. What would be the best solution for the program to "detect" this and when I recreate the table in the application, it will be recreated in the same way?

Comment: I would separate them using their corresponding div classes.

Comment: No problem! Next time you can help someone else with this! =)